# Is there a linting tool for projects on GitHub or GitLab?

Tags: software-development, git, github, lint

I just wondered if there's a linting tool (e.g. like Debian's [lintian](http://lintian.debian.org/)) for projects hosted on full-feature source code hosting platforms like GitHub or GitLab.

I'd imagine that such a tool could check things like the following:

- Is there a `README`/`README.*` file?
- Is there a `LICENSE` file? If not, it could refer to http://choosealicense.com/.
- Is there [a `CONTRIBUTING.md` file](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-guidelines-for-repository-contributors/)?
- Is the `README` file written in Markdown or another supported format which is rendered dynamically (like [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) or [AsciiDoc](http://www.asciidoc.org/))? Does it have a recognized file suffix?
- Is there a `.gitignore` file?
- Is the `LICENSE` file containing a license which is in accordance with GitHub's/GitLab's usage policy?
- Are there generated files (like e.g. `configure`) committed to the git repository?

Answer (score 1):

While researching for my question above, I already found one very promising linter named [flint](https://github.com/pengwynn/flint#readme). I haven't found it directly via some search engine but via [AtomLinter's Generic Linter listing](https://atomlinter.github.io/#misc).

I'd though be happy if others, who know other git project linting tools, would post their recommendation, too.